# Something or Somebody who is it?

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, tor

Well this is kind of strange to ask as I got a message while installing Tor: anonymity browser on my Ubuntu 16.04.

```
Setting up tor (0.2.9.8-2~xenial+1) ...
Something or somebody made /var/lib/tor disappear.
Creating one for you again.
Something or somebody made /var/log/tor disappear.
Creating one for you again.
```

can anyone kindly explain me what is this "Something or somebody" guy?

I found [this](https://gist.github.com/s4w3d0ff/c1f3af3fe27f0a4d2c98f0b4fd55b36f) link sarcastically (or actually) stating that its a magician...

[image: The Actual Image]

Comment: Have you had Tor on your system earlier?

Comment: Yeah I had but was always reluctant to ask this question !

Comment: I guess those folders were there because of the earlier installation. I don't think you need to be worried

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's just a funny way of saying this and that folders aren't there yet and need to be created.

Comment: Thanks, that's a strange way to say something is being created !

Comment: How is this not a comment?

Comment: @heynnema Normally I would agree but since the question is *can anyone kindly explain me what is this "Something or somebody" guy?* then this is the only answer. Had the question been different the answer would have to be expanded accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

This error could also happen when installing Tor before rebooting system after giving necessary admin privileges. If user is just created and then given some extra privileges like

```
usermod -aG sudo <user>
usermod -aG adm <user>
```

and then you try to install Tor you may get similar error. Reboot after privilege changes.